# How do I assign a value to a variable based on other observations of the same group

Tags: sas

For example, if I have a collection of individual records, organized into households, and I'd like to assign to the parents coresidentwithdaughter=1 to individuals who have a daughter, and coresidentwithson=1 to individuals who have a son how would I do that?

How would I code **coresidentwithdaughter** and **coresidentwithson** for the following result, given the variables of household number and relation

sample data:

**household** 703 703 703 703 703 703 
**sex** 1 2 2 2 1 1 
**age** 43 41 17 16 13 12
**relation** head spouse child child child child
**coresidentwithdaughter** 1 1 0 0 0 0 
**coresidentwithson** 1 1 0 0 0 0

**household** 704 704 704 **sex** 2 2 1 **age** 29 20 2 **relation** head sister child **coresidentwithdaughter** 0 0 0 **coresidentwithson** 1 0 0

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that `'child'` is the only relation to be deemed a son or daughter, and `'head'` and `'spouse'` are the only values allowed to be parents (not sure what you intended to do with 'sister'). The following will do the job using `PROC SQL`.

```
proc sql;
  select t.*,
  case when t.relation in ('head','spouse') and x.son then 1 else 0 end as coresidentwithson,
  case when t.relation in ('head','spouse') and x.daughter then 1 else 0 end as coresidentwithdaughter
  table t
  inner join
  (
    select 
    household, 
    sum(case when sex=1 then 1 else 0 end) as son
    sum(case when sex=2 then 1 else 0 end) as daughter
    from table
    where relation = 'child'
    group by 1
  ) x
  on t.household=x.household;
quit;
```

This is an example of a self-join, which is required when performing a query that refers back to the same group. This will also be possible using the `data-step`, but I don't have that solution.